# unable to set multiple bitmap in one imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

this is my activity in i am receiving bitmap and making multiple bitmap and show in one image view
i m getting multiple image but not set properly in image view   please help me ?

```
        private Bitmap Final_Murge_Bitmap() 
        {  
        Murge_Bitmap = null;
        try {

        Murge_Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(Murge_Bitmap);
        c.drawBitmap(Murge_Bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable3 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable4 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable5 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable6 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable7 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);
        Drawable drawable8 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap_recieve);

        drawable1.setBounds(220, 220, 501, 501);
        drawable2.setBounds(330, 330, 400, 400);
        drawable3.setBounds(160, 150, 200, 200);
        drawable4.setBounds(140, 120, 200, 200);
        drawable5.setBounds(120, 100, 400, 400);
        drawable6.setBounds(100, 80, 500, 500);
        drawable7.setBounds(80, 70, 200, 200);
        drawable8.setBounds(60, 60, 200, 200);

        drawable1.draw(c);
        drawable2.draw(c);
        drawable3.draw(c);
        drawable4.draw(c);
        drawable5.draw(c);
        drawable6.draw(c);
        drawable7.draw(c);
        drawable8.draw(c);

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return Murge_Bitmap;
    }}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to set bitmap in sequential format like gridview

Comment: why dont you use a GridView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like the following :

```
public Bitmap drawMultipleBitmapsOnImageView(Bitmap b) {
        Bitmap drawnBitmap = null;

        try {
            drawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);
                     // JUST CHANGE TO DIFFERENT Bitmaps and coordinates .
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 100, 100, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 200, 300, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 100, 200, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 300, 350, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return drawnBitmap;
    }
```

you call this method like the following :

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        Bitmap b = drawMultipleBitmapsOnImageView(bitmap);

        myImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

and please give me some feedback .

Hope that helps .

Comment: it's working and i need to scale image and save in but there is some problem in scaling i need code for scaling image and set on another image actually  i m working on photo editor app  can u please give me full source code for photo editor

Comment: ok but can please help me to scale bitmap image i m using Bitmap.createScaleBitmap(bitmap , 80,80,430,430);  ,Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 400,400 , true); both method not increasing my bitmap size

Answer (score 0):

You can draw everything like it was already said, or you can create a [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) with those BitmapDrawables. It is easier and consumes less memory, so if you can achieve what you want with this, do it.

```
private LayerDrawable createLayerDrawable() {
      Drawable layers = new Drawable[4];
      layers[0] = murge_drawable; // converted from Murge_Bitmap
      layers[1] = drawable1;
      layers[2] = drawable2;
      layers[3] = drawable3;
      // ...
      return new LayerDrawable(layers);
}

imageview.setImageDrawable(getLayerDrawable());
```