# Android - Imageview with multiple bitmaps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-glide, android-custom-drawable

I am working on a chat application, which does need to show the profile picture of each person whom I'm chatting with. If it is a group conversation I need to design a layout like `FB` as below

[image]

I'm thinking of implementing it using `LayerDrawable` but not sure how. Also the images need to be loaded from `server`. I'm using Glide library to load `images`.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41298499/2504274 I think it is what you needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered 3 layouts side by side and wrap the top layout into circular shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nz.co.example.components.CircleLinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_size"
android:orientation="horizontal"
custom:diameter="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_size"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/iv_left"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/line_spacing"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_half_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_half_size"
        android:id="@+id/iv_top_right"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_half_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/messaging_profile_pic_half_size"
        android:id="@+id/iv_bottom_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/line_spacing"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</nz.co.example.components.CircleLinearLayout>
```

And my Circular linearlayout code goes like this

```
public class CircleLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

private Bitmap maskBitmap;
private Paint paint, maskPaint;
private float radius;

public CircleLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null, 0);
}

public CircleLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CircleLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    if(attrs != null)
    {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes( attrs,R.styleable.CircleLinearLayout, defStyle , 0);

        try {
            radius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleLinearLayout_diameter, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.messaging_profile_pic_size)) / 2;
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

    super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

    if (maskBitmap == null) {
        maskBitmap = createMask(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
}

private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {
    Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    canvas.drawCircle(radius , radius , radius , paint);

    return mask;
   }
 }
```

Cheers,
Sree

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to implement `LayerDrawable`. On StackOverflow there are some examples like this below from [overlay two images in android to set an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview) issue

> You can skip the complex Canvas manipulation and do this entirely with
>   Drawables, using [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html).  You have one of two choices:
>   You can either define it in XML then simply set the image, or you
>   can configure a `LayerDrawable` dynamically in code.
>
> Solution #1 (via XML):
>
> Create a new Drawable XML file, let's call it `layer.xml`:
>
> ```
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:drawable="@drawable/t" />
>     <item android:drawable="@drawable/tt" />
> </layer-list>
> ```
>
> Now set the image using that Drawable:
>
> ```
> testimage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.layer));
> ```
>
> Solution #2 (dynamic):
>
> ```
> Resources r = getResources();
> Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
> layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.t);
> layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.tt);
> LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
> testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
> ```
>
> (I haven't tested this code so there may be a mistake, but this
>   general outline should work.)

Another possible solution might be from [unable to set multiple bitmap in one imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601025/unable-to-set-multiple-bitmap-in-one-imageview)

> you can do something like the following :
>
> ```
> public Bitmap drawMultipleBitmapsOnImageView(Bitmap b) {
>       Bitmap drawnBitmap = null;
>
>       try {
>           drawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Config.ARGB_8888);
>
>           Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);
>                      // JUST CHANGE TO DIFFERENT Bitmaps and coordinates .
>           canvas.drawBitmap(b, 100, 100, null);
>           canvas.drawBitmap(b, 200, 300, null);
>           canvas.drawBitmap(b, 100, 200, null);
>           canvas.drawBitmap(b, 300, 350, null);
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>       return drawnBitmap;
>   }
> ```
>
> you call this method like the following :
>
> ```
> ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
>       Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myImageView.getDrawable())
>               .getBitmap();
>       Bitmap b = drawMultipleBitmapsOnImageView(bitmap);
>
>       myImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
> ```

If you still feel not satisfied, take a look at [Android : How to Draw multiple images inside the same imageview but shifted in the y coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403140/android-how-to-draw-multiple-images-inside-the-same-imageview-but-shifted-in-t)

> use this code for show 2 image in one image:
>
> ```
>     ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
>     Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.call);
>     Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.available);
>     Bitmap combinedBitmap = getCombinedBitmap(pic2, pic1);
>
>     myImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
> ```
>
> and this is the **getCombinedBitmap()**  method :
>
> ```
> public Bitmap getCombinedBitmap(Bitmap b, Bitmap b2) {
>     Bitmap drawnBitmap = null;
>
>     try {
>         drawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
>
>         Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);
>         // JUST CHANGE TO DIFFERENT Bitmaps and coordinates .
>         canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);
>         canvas.drawBitmap(b2, 0, 0, null);
>         //for more images :
>         // canvas.drawBitmap(b3, 0, 0, null);
>         // canvas.drawBitmap(b4, 0, 0, null);
>
>     }
>     catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return drawnBitmap;
> }
> ```

You can also visit:
[Draw multiple bitmaps on Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612054/draw-multiple-bitmaps-on-imageview)

On Web you would also find some tutorials, but I don't think that presented there solution would be much different from this above.

---

Finally, once you've done it to make it circle use this library: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Hope it help

Comment: Checking the solution. Post you back soon